# Variable is being used but Golang lint complaining that the variable is not being used

Tags: go, lint, golangci-lint

Below is the code snippet where i have declared a for loop and getting index and box from the array of boxes. I am using the same index below in the if else block, but the golangci-lint is complaining about the variable index unused

```
func createMap(action string, boxes []Box, ratesMap FeeMap) []RateRes {

    resp := make([]RateRes, len(boxes))

    overrideKey := fmt.Sprintf("%s-*", action)

    for index, box := range boxes {
    
        key := fmt.Sprintf("%s-%s", action, boxes.label)
        rate, hasDefault := ratesMap[key]

        if hasDefault {
            resp[index] = RateRes{
                Code:  rate.Code,
                Label: box.label,
            }
        } else { 
            resp[index] = RateRes{
                Code:  RatesMap[overrideKey].Code,
                Label: box.label,
            }
        }

    }

    return resp
}
```

The exact error i am getting is :  `Error: index declared but not used (typecheck)`

Please suggest how to overcome this issue, which does not seem an issue.

Comment: can you edit your question to include the exact error you are seeing?

Comment: Have added the exact error @joshmeranda

Comment: Are you sure it is this section of code it is complaining about?

Comment: this seems correct, maybe the error is leading to a different snippet of code?

Comment: @BurakSerdar, yes it is complaining about this piece of code, in-fact it gives the exact line number in the error where the index variable is declared initialised.

Comment: `index` is used. Either you hit an edge case bug in linter, or this is not the code that's being linted.

Comment: This is the exact line where i am getting this error, i was also stumped by this error, and frankly speaking not very good at lint, so i posted it here.
Any way by which we can bypass it ? @BurakSerdar

Comment: Have you tried quitting your IDE and reopening? In VSCode I sometimes have issues where the Go language server hangs and it thinks errors are still present even when they have been resolved :)

Comment: @ThijsvanderHeijden I can try this, but this is just not on my local machine but also on the  circle ci where it runs all these security and sanity checks.

Answer (score 0):

In your `for loop` initialization statement you declare the `box` variable and it hasn't been used in the codes after that.

```
for index, box := range boxes {
```

please remove it if you are not using it change it like this.

```
for index := range boxes {
```

Comment: i have added the box field that is getting used in the if and else block